# Update Panel hindering jQuery function execution

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a simple aspx page which has two textboxes in an UpdatePanel.
I also have a jQuery function to sense function key F2 in these textboxes.
This jQuery function works perfectly if there is no UpdatePanel.
However, with UpdatePanel, this function is not executed at all.

The jQuery function is coded as follows:

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // function which will work for all textbox
    $(function Fun2() {

        // Execute if input type is textbox and 
        // if user performs keydown on this textbox
        $("input[type=text]").keydown(function () {

            // Check if F2 (ASCII 113) is pressed
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '113') {

                // Extract TextBox ID and Text Value
                var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
                var currentVal = $('#' + currentId + '').val();
                $('#HiddenBoxID').val(currentId);

                // alert user with TextBox ID and Text Value
                //alert('Textbox ID is : ' + currentId + ' and Textbox value is : ' + currentVal);

                // Trigger buttons click event
                $("#Button1").trigger('click');
            }                

        });           
    });
</script>
```

And my UpdatePanel looks like this:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenBoxID" runat="server"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="top: 103px; left: 701px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 128px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="top: 135px; left: 701px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 128px; bottom: 363px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="top: 173px; left: 701px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 135px" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Clear Message" style="top: 207px; left: 701px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 135px" />
        <asp:Label ID="MessLine" runat="server" style="top: 253px; left: 701px; position: absolute; height: 19px; width: 182px"></asp:Label>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

How can I get the function to execute while I still retain UpdatePanel?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('keydown',"input[type=text]",function(){});`

Comment: When adding the `UpdatePanel` the `id` attribute of all TextBoxes and Buttons is changed, and that makes your selectors not to work. Try using classes instead of the id.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Your suggestion worked, thanks a lot...

Comment: @Tasos K. Your suggestion worked, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you two changes:

1. Just don't put a name in the doc ready callback.
2. As there is auto generated ids happen to be in asp, so you can use `control.clientId`.

---

```
$(function() {
```

and change these lines as:

```
 $('#<%=HiddenBoxID.ClientID %>').val(currentId);
 $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup as below

```
// Adding ClientIDMode attribute so that your Jquery selectors are found.
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenBoxID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" style="top: 173px; left: 701px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 135px" />
```

and wrap your code inside [Page_Load](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/) function while using `UpdatePanel`

```
function Page_Load()
{
   // Your jquery code goes here
}
```